# How to compensate for daylight savings time PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database where the timestamps are stored like this:

`6/22/2022 11:00:00 AM EST`

or

`12/22/2022 11:00:00 AM EDT`

They are being saved as type TIMESTAMP(6).

I am needing to retrieve the dates in whatever time zone it currently is (EST or EDT), regardless of how it was saved. This must be done in PostgreSQL and not on the front-end.

Every answer I have seen mentions that a simple change in how the data is stored is the best solution. In my case, changing how the dates are already stored and how they will be stored going forward is not an option, so I must find another way.

Is this even possible?

Comment: you should have stored those values in a column defined as `timestamp with time zone` then Postgres would do that automatically for you. Never store timestamp values in a `varchar` (or `text`)  column.

Comment: 1) You are storing timestamps not dates 2)What is the data type for the columns that the timestamps are stored in? Add information as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I made that change as an update to the question: They are saved as TIMESTAMP(6).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Trust me, had I been there when this table was created, they would have been. I just updated the question to show that they are being saved as TIMESTAMP(6) values.

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have been reading the documentation and have not yet found an answer that fits my needs. I am actively looking, though. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Well, if it's a `timestamp` then it doesn't have a "format". Can't you just use `the_column at time zone '...'`

Comment: As others indicate you need to define your `timestamp with time zone`  (timestamptz). This will save it as UTC and convert it to your server time or a specified time zone. If you specify the time zone then **do not use time zone abbreviations** (EDT, EST, etc) but use the full timezone name (Amercia/New_York). The abbreviations are always a fixed offset from UTC, the full names however adjust for daylight savings (DST). See [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d5c235da0a2eff62ea00ea988f807825).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server has a `TimeZone` that covers `EST/EDT`:

```
show timezone;
     TimeZone     
------------------
 America/New_York


select '6/22/2022 11:00:00'::timestamp::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2022-06-22 11:00:00-04


select '12/22/2022 11:00:00'::timestamp::timestamptz;
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2022-12-22 11:00:00-05
```

To convert to formatted string:

```
select to_char('12/22/2022 11:00:00'::timestamp::timestamptz, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM TZ');
          to_char           
----------------------------
 12/22/2022 11:00:00 AM EST
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using your input:

```
SELECT  t AS input
    , t at time zone 'EDT' AS edt
    , t at time zone 'EST' AS est
FROM    (VALUES('12/22/2022 11:00:00 AM EDT'::timestamptz)) s(t);
```

This is what I get as output:

- 2022-12-22 16:00:00+01
- 2022-12-22 11:00:00
- 2022-12-22 10:00:00

For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC. When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone